# How many instances of AVAudioEngine should I create?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to use AVAudioEngine as the sound player for my iOS game. Are you supposed to use 1 instance of AVAudioEngine for the entire game, or an instance of it for each individual sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a single instance of AVAudioEngine and use separate instances of AVAudioPlayerNode connected to the engine for individual sounds.

You can find an example of this in Apple's [AVAEMixerSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVAEMixerSample/Listings/AVAEMixerSample_AudioEngine_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015134-AVAEMixerSample_AudioEngine_m-DontLinkElementID_6) example code.